# Div interchange is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my program. Here i wish to interchange selected div. when right click the div, first div will get selected and when left click another div, both div will interchange each other.  First time  all div will works correctly, and next time when we selected same div to interchange it won't work properly. Please help me to solve this issue...

Thanks in advance...

```
var asd = '';
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.cell').mousedown(function (event) {
        switch (event.which) {
            case 1:
                //left
                animateDiv($(this));
                break;
            case 3:
                //right
                asd = $(this);
                $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
                break;
        }
    });

    function animateDiv(This) {
        var new_pos = This.offset();
        var pos = asd.offset();
        asd.css('border-color', 'yellow');
        asd.animate({
            left: new_pos.left - pos.left,
            top: new_pos.top - pos.top
        }, 2000, function () {});
        This.animate({
            left: pos.left - new_pos.left,
            top: pos.top - new_pos.top
        }, 2000, function () {

        });
        asd = '';
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/winu/CEzLw/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/winu/CEzLw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your divs are in table cells and `offset` returns an offset relatively to a parent table cell. Divs don't change their cells, they just change position.

So possible solutions are:

- Do not use tables for this purpose

OR

- Move divs also physically to target table cell.

I would prefer the first solution without tables.

See updated [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CEzLw/3/). I've changed:

- function `placeCells` to render divs with their initial position
- `.cell` elements' position to `absolute`
- use `position` jquery function instead of `offset`
- changed `left` and `top` `animate`'s options